# How can i remove outliers in Python boxplot graph image?

Tags: python, max, boxplot, min, outliers

When I was organizing my skewed distribution data to boxplot in python, it has a lot of outliers. I want to show only maximum & minimum outlier.
How can I make a code?

I don't want to remove my database. Just I want to show two outliers(Max, Min) in my graph image.

Answer (score 1):

```
showfliers=False
```

or

```
plt.boxplot([data], showfliers=False)
```

try this ....